# Setting backgrounds of specific listview items by default

Tags: android

In my fragment I've been able control the backgrounds of my list item based on the clicking of an item in the list so for example if item 0 is clicked then its background is set to yellow and the backgrounds of the other list items are set GRAY.

I do all this in the onitemclicklistener and it works as expected. See code below:

```
    lvCodeType.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long id) {
            //lvCodeType.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC00"));

            //lvCodeType.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_rollover);

            if(position == 0) {
                desiredCodeType = "ABCD";

                lvCodeType.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_rollover);

                lvCodeType.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);
                lvCodeType.getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);
                lvCodeType.getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);
            } else if(position == 1) {
                desiredCodeType = "EFGH";

                lvCodeType.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);

                lvCodeType.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_rollover);

                lvCodeType.getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);
                lvCodeType.getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);
            } else if(position == 2) {
                desiredCodeType = "AGSOPA";

                lvCodeType.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);
                lvCodeType.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);

                lvCodeType.getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_rollover);

                lvCodeType.getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);                      
            } else if(position == 3) {
                desiredCodeType = "MNOP";

                lvCodeType.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);
                lvCodeType.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);
                lvCodeType.getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);

                lvCodeType.getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_rollover); 
            } else {
                desiredCodeType = "";

                lvCodeType.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);
                lvCodeType.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);
                lvCodeType.getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);
                lvCodeType.getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);
            }
        }
    });
```

Now I would like on the first time of loading this list before the user engages any of the list items I want to set the background of a specific list item so for example when the list loads up for the first time the background color of item 0 should be YELLOW with the background colors of the other items being GRAY.

I tried the following code in my fragment but outside the listview's onitemclicklistener after setting the list adapter but it failed:
                lvCodeType.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type_item_default);

Any ideas how I could go about this.

Below is my list code in my fragment:

```
// Inflate and customise code type listview
lvCodeType = (ListView) rlMain.findViewById(R.id.lv_codetype);
lvCodeType.setDividerHeight(2);
lvCodeType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgnd_lv_code_type);

lvCodeTypeData = new ArrayList<LVCodeTypeDrawer>();
lvCodeTypeData.add(new LVCodeTypeDrawer("ABCD"));
lvCodeTypeData.add(new LVCodeTypeDrawer("EFGH"));
lvCodeTypeData.add(new LVCodeTypeDrawer("IJKL"));
lvCodeTypeData.add(new LVCodeTypeDrawer("MNOP"));

lvCodeTypeAdapter = new LVCodeTypeAdapter(((MainActivity) getActivity()), 
                                            lvCodeType, 
                                            R.layout.lv_layout_code_type, 
                                            lvCodeTypeData, 
                                            officialRegularFont, 
                                            officialBoldFont);

lvCodeType.setAdapter(lvCodeTypeAdapter);
```

Below is my list adapter code:

```
public class LVCodeTypeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LVCodeTypeDrawer> {

    public static String TAG = "LVCodeTypeAdapter";
    Context context;
    List<LVCodeTypeDrawer> drawerItemList;
    int layoutID;
    public Typeface officialBoldFont, officialRegularFont;
    public ListView lvCodeType;

    public LVCodeTypeAdapter(Context context, ListView _lvCodeType, int _layoutResourceID, List<LVCodeTypeDrawer> listItems, 
            Typeface _officialRegularFont, Typeface _officialBoldFont) {

        super(context, _layoutResourceID, listItems);

        this.context = context;
        this.lvCodeType = _lvCodeType;
        this.layoutID = _layoutResourceID;
        this.drawerItemList = listItems;
        this.officialBoldFont =  _officialBoldFont;
        this.officialRegularFont = _officialRegularFont;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final int _position = position;

        LVCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder lvCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder;

        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();

            lvCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder = new LVCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder();

            view = inflater.inflate(layoutID, parent, false);

            lvCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder.itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_codetype);

            view.setTag(lvCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder);
        } else {
            lvCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder = (LVCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        LVCodeTypeDrawer dItem = (LVCodeTypeDrawer) this.drawerItemList.get(_position);

        lvCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder.itemName.setText(dItem.getCodeTypeValue());
        lvCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder.itemName.setTypeface(officialBoldFont);
        lvCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder.itemName.setTextSize(14.5f);
        lvCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder.itemName.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        return view;
    }

    private static class LVCodeTypeDrawerItemHolder {
        TextView itemName;
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: FYI: `lvCodeType.getChildAt(0)` is terrible. You are **NEVER** supposed to interact or keep a reference to a `View` inside a `ListView`. You should set the background in the `getView()` method of your `Adapter`. What you are currently doing is bad and unsafe.

Comment: @XaverKapeller: Thanks. So when u mention setting the background in the getView() method of my Adapter I'm a little bit clueless as I'm aware of how to set the background of all the list items but not and individual list item and as you correctly mention the use of lvCodeType.getChildAt(0) even in the view method is bad practice. Thanks